# Retrieving a parameter from GSP in Controller, Grails

Tags: model-view-controller, grails, controller, parameters

I do have this code on my demo.gsp file. But I´m new to grails and I don´t really know very well how to retrieve the value of the input on my Controller to validate it like i.e "inputResult=="hi" then ok else bad".

```
<g:form action='${postUrl}' method='post' id='loginForm' class='cssform' autocomplete='off'>
 <p>
   <label for="password">
    <g:message code="access.code"/>:
   </label>
 </p>
 <p>
   <input name="j_password" class="loghominput" id="password" type="password"/>
 </p>
 <div class="greenbutton2">
  <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('loginForm').submit(); return false">
  <g:message code="home.enter"/></a><input type="submit" style="display:none" value="Enter"/>
 </div>
</g:form>
```

My Controller is like this.

```
class AskDemoController {

    def demo = {

    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like the gsp for the spring security plugin.  I would suggest looking at the http://www.grails.org/Tutorials before jumping into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can access parameters submitted by your form in the controller by using the `params` object.  Something like this...

```
def somethingInTheForm = params.nameOfTheParam;

if (somethingInTheForm){
   render 'good'
}else{
   render 'bad'
}
```

Take a look [here](http://www.grails.org/Tag+-+form) for documentation.

**However** - i would suggest going through some to the [Tutorials](http://www.grails.org/Tutorials) to gain a better understanding of the power of grails.

Comment: You can also use params['nameOfTheParam'] to access parameters from the form.